# URLError fetching VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I m having an error while trying to fetch VGG16 using visual studio code.
The code is as shown

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

path = 'c:/Users/Eric koh/Desktop/Jupyter/ML Project/train/*.jpg'
train_path = 'c:/Users/Eric koh/Desktop/Jupyter/ML Project/train/'
df = pd.read_csv('c:/Users/Eric koh/Desktop/Jupyter/ML Project/labels.csv')

for file in glob.glob(path):
    id = (file.split("\\")[1]).split(".")[0]
    breed = df.loc[df.id == id]['breed'].values[0]
    if os.path.isdir(train_path + breed) is False:
        os.makedirs(train_path + breed)
    shutil.move(file, train_path +breed)

# Importing data
ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'int',
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (180, 180),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 111,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = 'training'
)
ds_validation = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'int',
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (180, 180),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 111,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = 'validation'
)

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=False, 
    weights='imagenet', 
    input_shape=(180,180,3), 
    classes=120,
    classifier_activation='softmax'
    )
```

The error happens when it tries to run tf.keras.applications.VGG16()

The error log is as shown

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/vgg16/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 275, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1420, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Eric koh/Desktop/Jupyter/ML Project/ML_on_dog_breed.py", line 111, in <module>
    model = model.VGG16.build(width, height)
  File "c:\Users\Eric koh\Desktop\Jupyter\ML Project\model.py", line 193, in build
    classifier_activation='softmax',
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\vgg16.py", line 221, in VGG16
    file_hash='6d6bbae143d832006294945121d1f1fc')
  File "D:\Program File (x86)\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 279, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/vgg16/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5: None -- unknown url type: https
```

I suspect it might be a connection error from VS code therefore unable to download it, however, I can't seem to get it to download VGG16. Is this a configuration error of sort?

Comment: Please post the *code*.

Comment: Somehow you have a python installation without SSL support, see the duplicate question for more details.